# Can't get shapes to move

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I'm trying to get 5 shapes generated randomly on my screen and have them with random sizes and rotate at random radii.

I have most of this already set up, except I can't get a few of my shapes to rotate, it's mostly the ones that are lineTo shapes (my triangles, rectanges and circles are working).

Here is a JSfiddle of my code, I'm thinking it has something to do with my drawing functions.

https://jsfiddle.net/y10ubvwr/

I appreciate any input!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Responsive Interactive Canvas</title>

</head>
<body>
<canvas id='canvas' width=1000 height=1000></canvas>
</body>   
<script>
var mainCanvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var mainContext = mainCanvas.getContext('2d');

var circles = new Array();
var squares = new Array();
var triangles = new Array();
var stars = new Array();
var diamonds = new Array();


var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || 
                            window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
                            window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
                            window.msRequestAnimationFrame;

 //intialize text variables
        var dashLen = 220;
        var dashOffset = dashLen;
        var speed = 5;
        var txt = 'ey';
        var x = 30; 
        var it = 0;


 //text properties
    mainContext.font = "50px Comic Sans MS, cursive, TSCu_Comic, sans-serif"; 
    mainContext.lineWidth = 5; 
    mainContext.lineJoin = "round";
    mainContext.globalAlpha = 2/3;
    mainContext.strokeStyle = mainContext.fillStyle = "#000";


//draw text function
 (function drawText() {
     mainContext.clearRect(x, 0, 60, 150);


     mainContext.setLineDash([dashLen - dashOffset, dashOffset - speed]);


      dashOffset -= speed;


      mainContext.strokeText(txt[it], x, 90);

      if (dashOffset > 0) requestAnimationFrame(drawText);
      else {

        mainContext.fillText(txt[it], x, 90);

        dashOffset = dashLen;


        x += mainContext.measureText(txt[it++]).width + mainContext.lineWidth * Math.random();


        mainContext.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3 * Math.random());


        mainContext.rotate(Math.random() * 0.005);


        if (it < txt.length) requestAnimationFrame(drawText);
      }
    })();  
function Circle(radius, speed, width, xPos, yPos) {
    this.radius = radius;
    this.speed = speed;
    this.width = width;
    this.xPos = xPos;
    this.yPos = yPos;
    this.opacity = .1 + Math.random() * .5;

    this.counter = 0;

    var signHelper = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);

    if (signHelper == 1) {
        this.sign = -1;
    } else {
        this.sign = 1;
    }
}

function Square(radius, speed, width, xPos, yPos) {
    this.radius = radius;
    this.speed = speed;
    this.width = width;
    this.xPos = xPos;
    this.yPos = yPos;
    this.opacity = .1 + Math.random() * .5;

    this.counter = 0;

    var signHelper = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);

    if (signHelper == 1) {
        this.sign = -1;
    } else {
        this.sign = 1;
    }
}

function Triangle(radius, speed, width, xPos, yPos) {
    this.radius = radius;
    this.speed = speed;
    this.width = width;
    this.xPos = xPos;
    this.yPos = yPos;
    this.opacity = .1 + Math.random() * .5;

    this.counter = 0;

    var signHelper = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);

    if (signHelper == 1) {
        this.sign = -1;
    } else {
        this.sign = 1;
    }
}

function Star(radius, speed, width, xPos, yPos) {
    this.radius = radius;
    this.speed = speed;
    this.width = width;
    this.xPos = xPos;
    this.yPos = yPos;
    this.opacity = .1 + Math.random() * .5;

    this.counter = 0;

    var signHelper = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);

    if (signHelper == 1) {
        this.sign = -1;
    } else {
        this.sign = 1;
    }
}

function Diamond(radius, speed, width, xPos, yPos) {
    this.radius = radius;
    this.speed = speed;
    this.width = width;
    this.xPos = xPos;
    this.yPos = yPos;
    this.opacity = .1 + Math.random() * .5;

    this.counter = 0;

    var signHelper = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);

    if (signHelper == 1) {
        this.sign = -1;
    } else {
        this.sign = 1;
    }
}
 //drawing circle
Circle.prototype.update = function () {
    this.counter += this.sign * this.speed;

    mainContext.beginPath();
    mainContext.arc(this.xPos + Math.cos(this.counter / 100) * this.radius, 
                    this.yPos + Math.sin(this.counter / 100) * this.radius, 
                    this.width, 
                    0, 
                    Math.PI * 2,
                    false);

    mainContext.closePath();

    mainContext.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 51,' + this.opacity + ')';
    mainContext.fill();
};

//drawing square
Square.prototype.update = function () {
    this.counter += this.sign * this.speed;


    mainContext.fillRect(this.xPos + Math.cos(this.counter / 100) *this.radius, this.yPos + Math.sin(this.counter / 100)*this.radius, 50, 50);

    mainContext.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 128, 51,' + this.opacity + ')';                

};
//drawing triangle
Triangle.prototype.update = function () {
    this.counter += this.sign * this.speed;

    mainContext.beginPath();
    mainContext.moveTo(this.xPos + Math.cos(this.counter / 100)*this.radius, (this.yPos + Math.sin(this.counter / 100)*this.radius));
    mainContext.lineTo((this.xPos + Math.cos(this.counter / 100)+50), (this.yPos + Math.sin(this.counter / 100)+100));
    mainContext.lineTo((this.xPos + Math.cos(this.counter / 100)+100), (this.yPos + Math.sin(this.counter / 100)+100));
    mainContext.closePath();
    mainContext.lineWidth = 10;
    mainContext.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 51, 51,' + this.opacity + ')';
    mainContext.fill();


};

//drawing cloud
Star.prototype.update = function () {

    mainContext.beginPath();
    mainContext.moveTo(this.xPos + Math.cos(this.counter / 100)*this.radius, (this.yPos + Math.sin(this.counter / 100)*this.radius));
    mainContext.lineTo((this.xPos + Math.cos(this.counter / 100)+50),(this.yPos + Math.sin(this.counter / 100)));
    mainContext.lineTo((this.xPos + Math.sin(this.counter / 100)+0), (this.yPos + Math.cos(this.counter / 100)+50));
    mainContext.lineTo(this.xPos + Math.cos(this.counter / 100), (this.yPos + Math.cos(this.counter / 100)+40));
    mainContext.closePath();
    mainContext.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 51, 153,' + this.opacity + ')';
    mainContext.fill();

}



Diamond.prototype.update = function () {

    mainContext.beginPath();
    mainContext.moveTo((this.xPos + Math.cos(this.counter / 100)+75)*this.radius,(this.yPos + Math.sin(this.counter / 100)*this.radius));

    mainContext.lineTo(this.xPos + Math.cos(this.counter / 100)+150,(this.yPos + Math.cos(this.counter / 100)+100));

    mainContext.lineTo(this.xPos + Math.cos(this.counter / 100)+75, (this.yPos + Math.cos(this.counter / 100)+200));

    mainContext.lineTo(this.xPos + Math.cos(this.counter / 100),(this.yPos + Math.cos(this.counter / 100)+100));
    mainContext.closePath();
    mainContext.fillStyle = 'rgba(102, 0, 204,' + this.opacity + ')';
    mainContext.fill();

}











function setupCircles() {
for (var i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    var randomX = Math.round(-200 + Math.random() * 700);
    var randomY = Math.round(-200 + Math.random() * 700);
    var speed = .2 + Math.random() * 3;
    var size = 5 + Math.random() * 100;
    var radius = 5 + Math.random() * 100;

    var circle = new Circle(radius, speed, size, randomX, randomY);
    circles.push(circle);
}
drawAndUpdate();
}
setupCircles();

function setupSquares() {
for (var i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    var randomX = Math.round(-100 + Math.random() * 700);
    var randomY = Math.round(-100 + Math.random() * 700);
    var speed = .05 + Math.random() * 3;
    var size = 5 + Math.random() * 100;
    var radius = 5 + Math.random() * 100;

    var square = new Square(radius, speed, size, randomX, randomY);
    squares.push(square);
}
drawAndUpdate();
}
setupSquares();

function setupTriangles() {
for (var i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    var randomX = Math.round(-100 + Math.random() * 700);
    var randomY = Math.round(-100 + Math.random() * 700);
    var speed = .05 + Math.random() * 3;
    var size = 5 + Math.random() * 100;
    var radius = 5 + Math.random() * 100;

    var triangle = new Triangle(radius, speed, size, randomX, randomY);
    triangles.push(triangle);
}
drawAndUpdate();
}
setupTriangles();

function setupStars() {
for (var i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    var randomX = Math.round(-100 + Math.random() * 700);
    var randomY = Math.round(-100 + Math.random() * 700);
    var speed = .2 + Math.random() * 3;
    var size = 5 + Math.random() * 100;
    var radius = 5 + Math.random() * 100;

    var star = new Star(radius, speed, size, randomX, randomY);
    stars.push(star);
}
drawAndUpdate();
}
setupStars();


 function setupDiamonds() {
for (var i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    var randomX = Math.round(-100 + Math.random() * 700);
    var randomY = Math.round(-100 + Math.random() * 700);
    var speed = .2 + Math.random() * 3;
    var size = 5 + Math.random() * 100;
    var radius = 5 + Math.random() * 100;

    var diamond = new Diamond(radius, speed, size, randomX, randomY);
    diamonds.push(diamond);
}
drawAndUpdate();
}
setupDiamonds();


function drawAndUpdate() {
mainContext.clearRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);


for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {

    var myCircle = circles[i];
    myCircle.update();
}
for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {

     var mySquare = squares[i];
    mySquare.update();
}

for (var i = 0; i < triangles.length; i++) {

     var myTriangle = triangles[i];
    myTriangle.update();
}

for (var i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {

     var myStar = stars[i];
    myStar.update();
}

for (var i = 0; i < diamonds.length; i++) {

     var myDiamond = diamonds[i];
    myDiamond.update();
}

requestAnimationFrame(drawAndUpdate);
}


</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/y10ubvwr/1/

```
//drawing cloud
Star.prototype.update = function () {
  this.counter += this.sign * this.speed;
    mainContext.save()
    mainContext.beginPath();
  mainContext.translate(Math.cos(this.counter /100)*this.radius, Math.sin(this.counter / 100)*this.radius);
    mainContext.moveTo(this.xPos, this.yPos);
    mainContext.lineTo((this.xPos +50),(this.yPos ));
    mainContext.lineTo((this.xPos +0), (this.yPos +50));
    mainContext.lineTo(this.xPos, (this.yPos+40));
    mainContext.closePath();
    mainContext.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 51, 153,' + this.opacity + ')';
    mainContext.fill();
mainContext.restore()
}
```

You forgot the counter update in the diamond and star updates functions.

Also you are moving point by point in every shape, forgetting to put the radius in some of the points.
Notice how is smoother the animation using context.translate instead of manually calculate the position of everypont multiple time per update funciont.
You are calling Math.cos and Math.sin up to 8 times per shape while you can call just once.

Comment: Wow, I'm dumb for not seeing that and putting that in the other shapes.  I didn't know about that .translate function at all as well :O

I appreciate it!

Also i had just a quick question that is kind of related to this.

If I wanted to add a function like an onClick or button press event to say hide the visibility of the whole canvas or make it refresh the canvas for more randomness, 

would I only have to make a new function for that event and fiddle only with that or do I have to go into each and every shape and change things as well?

Comment: after  you look so much at same code is normal. for your question can you explain better? (take care that context.translate comes with a save and restore before and after, also context.rotate and context.scale is interesting)

Comment: Well I want to add 2 things, when you click on the canvas, everything changes to color white or when you press the up key, the canvas refreshes.  Can that be done in only one function?